# How to retrieve a complete list of flowfiles in a specific queue in NiFi using the API or UI

Tags: apache-nifi, nifi-api

I need to retrieve all flowfiles in a specific queue in NiFi, but the API only returns up to 100 results at a time. My queue contains 358 flowfiles, so I need a way to retrieve all of them

Below are the API am using for get the flowfiles.

API : https://myserver.com:myport/nifi-api/flowfile-queues/ba619122-3c65-3279-a2ba-b3ad89f8a429/listing-requests/903d485f-d4aa-102a-0000-0112e4a15ea

```
{
    "listingRequest": {
        "id": "903d485f-d4aa-102a-0000-0112e4a15ea",
        "uri": "https://myserver.com:myport/nifi-api/flowfile-queues/ba619122-3c65-3279-a2ba-b3ad89f8a429/listing-requests/903d485f-d4aa-102a-0000-0112e4a15ea",
        "submissionTime": "10/18/2023 17:07:57.632 IST",
        "lastUpdated": "17:07:57 IST",
        "percentCompleted": 1,
        "finished": true,
        "maxResults": 100,
        "state": "Completed successfully",
        "queueSize": {
            "byteCount": 3792,
            "objectCount": 350
        },
        "flowFileSummaries": [
            {
                "HERE IS THE FLOW FILES TILL 100TH POSITIONS": 100
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. The provided link is nothing but your local one ...

Comment: looks like 100 hardcoded in nifi code. https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-web/nifi-web-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/web/dao/impl/StandardConnectionDAO.java#L361 what's your use-case? why do you need it?

Comment: Hi @daggett, I need to develop a way to visualize all flowfiles in a queue. I will use NiFi APIs to retrieve the flowfiles and a GUI to display them.

Comment: I don't see other option but change nifi code to add pagination for queue api. Luckily it's opensource.

Comment: Yes, That would be last call. Thanks!